# Split a string with regular expression lookarounds using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to use `String.prototype.split` to split the string if the previous character is not equal to the next character, here's the target result:

> 'abcd' => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>
> 'aaabbbccd' => ['aaa', 'bbb', 'cc', 'd']

I know it's possible to split a string by only `lookbacks`:

```js
const result = 'aaabbbccd'.split(/(?<=a)/);
console.log(result);  // ["a", "a", "a", "bbbccd"]
```

So I wanted to find an expression to find the delimiter of two characters that its lookback is not equal to lookahead.

But I tried this, and it doesn't work:

```js
const result = 'aaabbcccd'.split(/(?<!\2)(?=.)/);
console.log(result);  // ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd']
```

So is there a regular expression to achieve this? Or it's just simply impossible to do that with regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using backreferences, you can use `.match()` instead of `.split()` to get your desired result like so:

```js
const r1 = 'abcd'.match(/(.)\1*/g);
const r2 = 'aaabbcccd'.match(/(.)\1*/g);
console.log(r1); // ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
console.log(r2); // ['aaa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'd']
```

This will match any character `(.)`, followed by the same character `\1` zero or more times